# Get index of the minimum of multi-index Pandas DataFrame using level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) that is [multiindexed](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) and want to find the minimum value of a certain column in a subset of rows on each level, and get the entire contents of those rows.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['v1', 'v2'],
                                  ['record' + str(i) for i in range(1, 7)]])

df = pd.DataFrame([[2., 114], [2., 1140],
                   [3., 114], [3., 1140],
                   [5., 114], [5., 1140],
                   [2., 114], [2., 1140],
                   [3., 114], [3., 1140],
                   [5., 114], [5., 1140]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'],
                  index=idx)
```

My structure:

```
                 col1  col2
level1 level2
v1     record1    2.0   114
       record2    2.0  1140
       record3    3.0   114
       record4    3.0  1140
       record5    5.0   114
       record6    5.0  1140
v2     record1    2.0   114
       record2    2.0  1140
       record3    3.0   114
       record4    3.0  1140
       record5    5.0   114
       record6    5.0  1140
```

---

**Example desired output I want the minimum value of another column where `col1 == 5`:**

```
                 col1  col2
level1 level2
v1     record5    5.0   114
v2     record5    5.0   114
```

---

I know that I can get a subset of rows by using a comparison statement.

```
df.ix[df['col1'] == 5]
```

And I also know that I can get the minimum *values* of a column within that subset from *all levels*.

```
df['col2'][df['col1'] == 5].min(level='level1')
```

And if I want to specify the level, then I can get the *index* of 1 row *on specific level*.

```
df.ix['v1', pay_up_file.ix['v1']['col2'][(df.ix['v1']['col1'] == 5)].idxmin()]
```

But I cannot figure out if there is an efficient way to get the *indexes* from *all levels*

There does not seem to be a method available along the lines of this:

```
df['col2'][df['col1'] == 5].idxmin(level='level1')
```

I can get to what I want with this:

```
df.ix[
  (df['col1'] == 5) & 
  (df['col2'].isin(df['col2'][df['col1'] == 5].min(level='level1').values))
]
```

But with everything else that is in `Pandas`, is there a better way to get to my output?

Comment: It is at the top, but i bolded it and put some larger line breaks to make it more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.loc[df.loc[df.col1 == 5.].groupby(level=0).col2.idxmin()]

            col1  col2
v1 record5   5.0   114
v2 record5   5.0   114
```

#### Note

I'm using `idxmin` as you thought you ought to.  But the context matters.  I'm using it following a `groupby(level=0).col2.idxmin()` which acts as you thought `col2.idxmin(level=...)` should.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> (df[df.col1 == 5]
     .groupby(level=0, as_index=False).col2
     .apply(lambda group: group.nsmallest(1))
0  v1  record5    114
1  v2  record5    114
dtype: int64
```

Or...

```
>>> df[df.col1 == 5].groupby(level=0).col2.nsmallest(1)
v1  v1  record5    114
v2  v2  record5    114
dtype: int64
```

But I'm not sure why the first level shows twice (i.e. 'v1'  'v1'  ...).

Comment: Wouldn't `.nth(0)` just take the first row, rather than the minimum? In my example, the minimum was always the first, but that might not always be the case in production